# Convert decimal to percent or shift decimal places. How

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a that is generated from the diference of 2 numbers, but it return for exemple 0,07 for 7% and 0,5 for 50% i just want to fix to reach these goar, like 15,2% 13% and so on. How can I do that? do c# has something embeded on CLR to do that?

Comment: You mean, other than multiplying the result by 100?

Answer (score 27):

You can use the [Percentage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierPct) Custom [Numeric Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).  This will do it without you having to multiply yourself.

For example, you can do:

```
double value = 0.152;
string result = value.ToString("#0.##%");
```

If your locale is set to European (my guess based off the format you wrote), you'll get a string with the value of "15,2%".

You can also just use the Standard Percentage ("P") [Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), if you're happy with the default formatting.

Comment: I agree that this is the better answer, I had forgotten about those.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look there : [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString)

```
 double number = .2468013;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("P", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 24.68 %
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("P", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hr-HR")));
// Displays 24,68%     
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("P1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 24.7 %
```